# How would I remove all leading alphabetical characters?

Tags: excel, vba

I am interested in removing leading alphabetical (alpha) characters from cells which appear in a column. I only wish to remove the leading alpha characters (including UPPER and LOWER case): if alpha characters appear after a number they should be kept. Some cells in the column might not have leading alpha characters.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
36173
PIL51014
4UNV22001
ZEB54010
BICMPAFG11BK
BICMPF11
```

Notice how there are not always the same number of leading alpha characters. I cannot simply use a Left or Right function in Excel, because the number of characters I wish to keep and remove varies.

A correct output for what I am looking for would look like:

```
36173
51014
4UNV22001
54010
11BK
11
```

Notice how the second to last row preserved the characters "BK", and the 3rd row preserved "UNV". I cannot simply remove all alpha characters.

I am a beginner with visual basic and was not able to figure out how to use excel functions to address my issue. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an Excel formula that will "strip off the leading alpha characters"  Actually, it looks for the first numeric character, and returns everything after that:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"0123456789")),99)
```

The `99` at the end needs to be some value longer than the longest string you might be processing.  `99` usually works.

Comment: For some reason this formula is not outputting anything. I am pressing ctrl+shift+enter. I entered it the way you have it (but with commas instead of semicolon), but instead of an output when I press ctrl+shift+enter it still shows the formula in the cell.

Comment: @JoeDolan  It works fine here.  Changing the semicolons to commas within the array constant, and/or using CSE vs just E, should not make any difference.  If your original data does not contain a digit, then, as designed, there will not be any output.  Are there leading characters not to be removed that are other than non-digits?  e.g symbols or Unicode characters?  There were none in your examples.  The other issue might be that the cell reference is incorrect.  I used `A1`, but maybe you need to change that.

Comment: @JoeDolan   If the above discussion doesn't help, post a copy of a workbook showing the problem to some public site, and post a link here.

Comment: It worked once I tried it on a different workbook. Not sure what was wrong the first time, but it is all good now.

Comment: @JoeDolan I misswrote. The problem is a setting that has it showing formulas instead of the calculation in **Options** or on the formula tab.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a formula based solution complete with test results:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"),255),100)
```

[image]

Change the `100` at the end if any string may be longer than 100 characters. Also the 255 is not needed, but it won't hurt.

Comment: For some reason this formula is not outputting anything. I am pressing ctrl+shift+enter. I entered it the way you have it, and tried removing the 255, but instead of an output when I press ctrl+shift+enter it still shows the formula in the cell.

Comment: @JoeDolan - yes, it had to do with your excel settings. you probably inadvertently turned the option on to show formulas in the cells. and you don't to enter it as an array formula.

Answer (score 2):

This short UDF should strip off leading alphabetic characters.

```
Function noLeadAlpha(str As String)
    If Not IsNumeric(str) Then
        Do While Asc(str) < 48 Or Asc(str) > 57
            str = Mid(str, 2)
            If Not CBool(Len(str)) Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End If
    noLeadAlpha = str
End Function
```

[image: udf_no_leading_alphas]

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Koodos Jeeped, you beat me to it.

But here is an alternative anyway:

```
Function RemoveAlpha(aString As String) As String

    For i = 1 To Len(aString)
        Select Case Mid(aString, i, 1)
            Case "0" To "9"
                RemoveAlpha = Right(aString, Len(aString) - i + 1): Exit For
        End Select
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate the time you took.